# Jquery start countdown on mouseenter div then show image on "0"

Tags: jquery

I don't know much about jquery but I know this is the only way I will achieve this effect.

Code at the moment:

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var settimmer = 0;
    $(function(){
            window.setInterval(function() {
                var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
                var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
                $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);

                if(updateTime <= 0){
                    $("#timer").load("images/logo.png");
                }
            }, 1000);

    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="timerwrap"> <div id="my-timer"> <b id="show-time">100</b> </div> </div>
```

I was wondering it anyone could help make it so when I mouseenter the surrounding div the countdown starts then change a background image in the #timerwrap when the timer hits "0"?

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points first.

When using an id you dont need a selector like `b[id=show-time]` just use `#show-time`.

Second, you should always avoid `eval`, plus what you actually want is to `parseInt` - and of course you never need to eval a literal number.

```
var updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter,10) - 1;
```

Now, to answer your question, you eed to execute your function inside an event handler for `mouseover`. Also, you should only start the timer once, and remember to stop it when it reaches 0

```
$(function(){
    var timerId = 0;
    $('#timerwrap').mouseover(function(){
        if(timerId == 0){
            timerId = window.setInterval(function() {
                var timeCounter = $("#show-time").html();
                var updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter,10) - 1;
                $("#show-time").html(updateTime);

                if(updateTime <= 0){
                    clearTimeout(timerId);
                    $("#timer").css({background:"url(images/logo.png)"});
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
 });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vEsxC/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for your help and explaining it.
One more little question: When I change #show-time to #container4 it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I mean, if I wanted to start the timer by mouseover a separate div not containing the timer? Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. I figured it out. I feel like such a n00b. Thanks!